# 2D animation inside video editing query

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor

Very new to blender video editing, I have found an animated style I want to replicate (gif below) and include in a video but I don't know what it's called and thus cannot look for a tutorial without knowing the jargon around it. It's the character shadow animation bit in the gif.

Could someone please point me in the right direction or give me a name of what this might be called? Assume I have no prior knowledge of animating or creating mattes in blender, where do I start if I want to animate a frame of video like the example and put it back in the target video? Cheers in advance

[image: sampleanim]

Comment: External links are not permanent, please add screen or anim gif of desired result into your question. Thank you keep this site organized.

Comment: If you are referring to white silhouette offset from character you need to matte character (for Compositor use Cryptomatte pass or for video editor render separately) ... in both cases you will use matte as a mask for mixing foreground -white "shadow" - background.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Asking for links to resources about X is considered off topic here, asking directly about X is encouraged though. If you can rephrase your question to focus on the specific difficulties you are encountering, rather than point you to some site, please [edit] your post so it can be reopened. As it stands it is not a good fit for this site.

Comment: Thankyou for the replies. All of that goes over my head. Assuming I have no prior knowledge with animation, what is the name of the process I need to learn to take a frame of video, create a matte of a subject and animate it to move to a side? I don't even know what that flow chart bit is called or where to find it in blender. I get that this is painful but how else do I learn the name of what I need to learn y'know? Most tutorial assume huge amounts of prior knowledge on the subject and I have none. where do I start?

Comment: In Blender you can use *Compositing* or *Video Editor* to accomplish this task, so search for that to learn basics in tutorials. If you would be more friendly with blenders environment you can check how to setup such thing in my answers.  Because if you don't know nothing about that I don't know where to start either. Also I don't think this effect has some specific name :) Thanks for edits I voted for Reopening now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example

Compositor > Cryptomatte

[image]
[image]

[image]

Video Editor

Render character with Alpha (transparent background) and background. For simplicity here I used for white "shadow" just a copy of cube strip, added Curve Modifier to make it white and white G (grab) and S (scale) I shifted strip.

[image]

[image]